# C homework - string loops replacements

Tags: c, string, replace

I know it's a little unorthodox and will probably cost me some downvotes, but since it's due in 1 hour and I have no idea where to begin I thought I'd ask you guys.

Basically I'm presented with a string that contains placeholders in + form, for example:

```
1+2+5
```

I have to create a function to **print out all the possibilities of placing different combinations of any given series of digits**. I.e. for the series:

```
[9,8,6] // string array
```

The output will be

```
16265
16285
16295
18265
18285
18295
19265
19285
19295
```

So for each input I get (number of digits)^(number of placeholders) lines of output.
Digits are 0-9 and the maximum form of the digits string is `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.
The original string can have many placeholders (as you'd expect the output can get VERY lengthly).

I have to do it in C, preferably with no recursion. Again I really appreciate any help, couldn't be more thankful right now.

**If you can offer an idea, a simplified way to look at solving this, even in a different language or recursively, it'd still be ok, I could use a general concept and move on from there.**

Comment: It would take me thirty seconds to write this program in C++, but I can't crack out C in that time. Sorry.

Comment: C++ could be good too, I'll just have to translate it somehow. Please help!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid recursion?  This problem can be reduced to computing all the possibilities of `nCr` where `n` is the number of + signs and `r` is the number digits in the series.  This is most easily solved recursively.

Comment: @sombe: Ok. Is the series string array in compile-time form or also entered at runtime?

Comment: @Niki Yoshiuchi I know, but those were the instructions (pre CS, don't ask...)

Comment: What have you tried already? Labeling something as `homework` doesn't remove the issue that you've done absolutely nothing by yourself. Show us what effort you've already made and then we'll help. Without demonstrating you're trying to help yourself, I'm certainly not going to aid in yet another student pass a subject they blatantly don't understand.

Comment: -1: `due in 1 hour and I have no idea where to begin`

Comment: @OJ I know the subject very well, I don't know how to approach this. I haven't done anything that actually works, so I was looking for guidance there. Again sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints them in different order, but it does not matter. and it's not recursive.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int // 0 if no more.
get_string(char* s, const char* spare_chr, int spare_cnt, int comb_num){
    for (; *s; s++){
        if (*s != '+') continue;
        *s = spare_chr[comb_num % spare_cnt];
        comb_num /= spare_cnt;
    };
    return !comb_num;
};

int main(){
    const char* spare_str = "986";
    int num = 0;
    while (1){
        char str[] = "1+2+5";
        if (!get_string(str, spare_str, strlen(spare_str), num++)) 
            break; // done
        printf("str num %2d: %s\n", num, str);
    };
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Do you know why it only prints the first option and not all of them?

Comment: All of them. (just `#include <string.h>` so that it would actually compile).

Comment: I need the exact order I wrote it. They compare the output with theirs.

Comment: @sombe: At least instead of a boring homework you have a nice reverse engineering problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do the actual replacement, you can use `strchr` to find the first occurrence of a character and return a `char *` pointer to it. You can then simply change that pointer's value and bam, you've done a character replacement.

Because `strchr` searches for the first occurrence (before a null terminator), you can use it repeatedly for every value you want to replace.

The loop's a little trickier, but let's see what you make of this.